# sh: out of memory for system call

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, arm, sh

I am running the following code on an ARM Based board:

```
void MainLoop()
{
    char command[256];
    int ret = 0;
    int loopCount = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        memset(command, '\0', sizeof(command));
        sprintf(command, "/usr/bin/gst-launch-0.10 imxv4l2src ! imxv4l2sink &");
        ret = system(command);
        printf("StartStreamer: command=[%s], status:%d\n", command, ret);
        if ( ret != 0 )
        {
            ret = system("reboot");
            printf("Rebooting:%d\n", ret);
        }
        sleep(15);
        memset(command, '\0', sizeof(command));
        sprintf(command, "killall gst-launch-0.10");
        ret  = system(command);
        printf("StopStreamer: command=[%s], status = %d\n", command, ret);
        if ( ret != 0 )
        {
            ret = system("reboot");
            printf("Rebooting:%d\n", ret);
        }
        sleep(15);
        loopCount++;
        printf("Loop Count:%d\n", loopCount);

    }
}
```

After running some random loops I am getting the following error:

```
sh: out of memory
StartStreamer: command=[/usr/bin/gst-launch-0.10 imxv4l2src ! imxv4l2sink &], status:256
Segmentation fault
Rebooting:35584
StopStreamer: command=[killall gst-launch-0.10], status = 11
Rebooting:11
Loop Count:26
sh: relocation error: sh: symbol free, version GLIBC_2.4 not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference
sh: relocation error: sh: symbol free, version GLIBC_2.4 not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference
StartStreamer: command=[/usr/bin/gst-launch-0.10 imxv4l2src ! imxv4l2sink &], status:32512
Rebooting:11
killall: gst-launch-0.10: no process killed
StopStreamer: command=[killall gst-launch-0.10], status = 11
Rebooting:11
Loop Count:27
StartStreamer: command=[/usr/bin/gst-launch-0.10 imxv4l2src ! imxv4l2sink &], status:32512
Rebooting:32512
```

Can you please tell me what does "sh: Out of Memory" means, is it because of too many system calls.. Also, its wierd that iam getting relocation error in glibc...

I have modified from C Application to Bash script:

```
#!/bin/ash
count=0
    while [ true ];do
            echo "Starting Streamer"
        /usr/bin/gst-launch-0.10 imxv4l2src ! imxv4l2sink &
            sleep 15
            echo "Stopping Streamer"
            killall gst-launch-0.10
            sleep 15
            count=$((count+1))
            echo $count
    done
```

And after running for some loop I get the following errors:

*** Error in `/bin/sh': double free or corruption (out): 0x0028ebf8 ***
*** Error in`/bin/sh': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0028edf8 ***

Comment: If it is not your program that is misusing memory, then it must be one of the programs you launch that cause the board to run out of memory.

Comment: Can you please tell me the commands to check the memory usage of the program

Answer (score 1):

> Can you please tell me what does "sh: Out of Memory" means, is it because of too many system calls.

From the `system` man page:

```
   The  system()  library  function  uses  fork(2)  to create a child
   process that executes the shell command specified in command using
   execl(3) as follows:

       execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *) 0);

   system() returns after the command has been completed.
```

I'd say this is why you're seeing that message.  You've apparently run out of resources for the `fork` part.  Whether this is running into an rlimit or just running the board out of memory (more likely)  it's hard to tell.

So basically you've got a main loop which calls `system`, which "under the hood" creates a copy of your process and copies the binary (the `execl` part) into the copy.  Oh and you attempt to `killall` the first process (by `system`, again).  Unfortunately, signals aren't guaranteed to be reliable, but are usually received.  Another piece of complexity is that you're at the mercy of the scheduler which may not run the process when you think it will.

It'd be better to access this functionality using the more primitive `fork`/`exec` functions -- at least  you'd have the PID to send the signal without the overhead of the `killall`.

Comment: Is it not same the killall vs killing using the PID. In the former case, killall is retrieving the PID..

Comment: Not really.  `killall` in this case is another process which is `fork`ed off (using more memory), which reads the process table searching for a match to send a signal (e.g. `kill`) to the PID.  `kill` doesn't `fork`, avoiding overhead and memory use.

Comment: Are you saying using killall with system() creates two process, one created by system and the other of killall and whereas with kill using system(), it only creates one process... Please Confirm.

Comment: I'm not talking about the [`kill` command line utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/kill.html), I'm talking about the [`kill` system call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/kill.html) (which sends a signal to a process).  Anythiing you call using `system` is going to `fork` (create a copy of the executing process).